# Copy and Paste in excel 2007 using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with this, as a group we have to open 23 excel files and copy and paste their contents into a model (another workbook). Each of the 23 excel workbooks has 3 worksheets that need to be converted into 1. We need to do all this at the click of a button using vba any suggestions?

Comment: Our model should end up looking like 23 worksheets in one big workbook, instead of 69 worksheets in 23 workbooks as is the current situation mmmmmm

Comment: Have you considered importing all of them into a database instead of a monster xls file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are asking here?

What you want to do is fairly simple... if you have an issue with a specific part I'd be happy to help.

As an overview I'd most likely us an FSO to navigate the file strucutre and import the sheets into a collection of arrays. These could then be looped at on the destination sheet.

There are more elegent methods but without knowing more details it's ahrd to help.